# Best way to load modules in my view using backbone?

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, requirejs

I'm a new user in backbone and require.js . I created a web application using requirejs using both define and require keyword. I have a doubt in it, which is the correct method to load among :-

```
define(
    ['jquery',
    'underscore',
    'backbone',
    'app/models/dashboardmodel',
    'text!tpl/DashboardView.html',
    ],
function($, _, Backbone, models, tpl){

"use strict";
```

or

```
define(function (require) {

"use strict";

var $           = require('jquery'),
    Backbone    = require('backbone'),
    PageSlider  = require('app/utils/pageslider'),
    DashView    = require('app/views/dashboard'),
    dashview    = new DashView();
```

If anybody please explain me detail. Also I don't know the importance of the statement :

```
use strict;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my practice i use first way of define, IMHO its more readable + it lets you be sure that all sub modules are loaded and you can use all of them in callback. Next advantage you can see how many dependencies you module have- if there are to much its reason for refactoring :)

Answering you second question: use strict;  - you can checkout this [article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/Strict_mode) 
In a few words its language construction that does not allow to some language construction and helps to code in the right way.